# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to open a project from github on android studio 2022.21.1 with gradle.
I've an issue with the following message :Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0

I've downloaded the 8.1.1 version and edit the local varibale environement in windows by adding the gradle path.

in the build.gradle file, I've change the classpath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'

Now i've the following error : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.
Can you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot
Max

Answer (score 1):

The `com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version` is what we called Android Gradle Plugin (AGP), its latest stable version is `8.0.0` (Apr 13, 2023), you can check all available versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google)

Compatibility with Gradle you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: Android Studio downloaded gradle 8 when I started the new project.
Why would I need to download it again outside of the IDE?